# Mongooose query where ObjectId is null?

Tags: mongoose

How can I search for a document doing a `.findOne` where an `ObjectId` field is not set?  I cannot find if I should be searching on `null` or `undefined` or something else.

In the example below, I'm trying to find a document where the "email" value IS known but the userId has not yet been set:

```
var joinRequest = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: { type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true },
    code: { type: String, uppercase: true, trim: true, select: false  },
    lastSent: { type: Date },
    userId: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, select: false }
});
```

Then again, can an `ObjectId` field ever be null?  Should I use a `String` here?

Comment: to the best of my knowledge _id will always have a readonly guid assigned to it

Comment: This is not the _id field.  It is a field with a type of ObjectId.  I'm attempting to use undefined, however WebStorm is highlighting it as a variable which makes me worry.

Comment: i don't think the `findOne` function will look at properties with the `undefined` value when matching thus making it find the very first document everytime (i also don't think mongodb will store undefined), instead search by `null` and store `null`

Comment: I tried to implement a field like you which was a `objectId` type but when I inserted a null/undefined value I get the error `Cast to ObjectID failed for value`, so I reverted back to string type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Few things about `undefined` in the context of MongoDB

Properties with the value `undefined` are not stored. So the following will have no `a` property

```
db.insert({a : undefined})
```

However for arrays the `undefined` values are converted to `null`

```
db.insert({a : [undefined]}) //stores {a : [null]}
```

Also `undefined` has weird behaviors when used as a condition

```
db.users.find({a : undefined}) //finds everything
db.users.findOne({a : undefined}) //always returns the first document (which is a problem for you)
db.users.update({a : undefined}, {a : true}) //only updates documents with no a property
```

So I would avoid the use of `undefined` and probably pretend it doesn't even exist. Use `null` instead since it is stored and does't sometimes get dropped as a condition.

So for example

```
db.users.insert({email : "email@domain.com", userID : null});
db.users.findOne({email : "email@domain.com", userID : null});
```

If you decide to use undefined though do it like this

```
db.users.insert({email : "email@domain.com"});
db.users.findOne({email : "email@domain.com", userID : { exists : false }}); //works for null as well
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

Comment: definitely store `null`...or you could resort to the `$exists` operator http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/